# Shall we call this relation an "isomorphism"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

*This is a short question:*

Assume the values: $\mathbf{True}$, $\mathbf{False}$

and the logic symbols: $\land,\lor$

Is $\mathbf{True}$, $\mathbf{False}$ under $\land,\lor \,$ isomorphic to $\boldsymbol{0},\boldsymbol{1}$ under $\cdot, +$?

Can you explain why or why not?

Comment: $\{0,1\}$ is not closed under "normal" addition: $1+1=2\notin\{0,1\}$

Comment: But $\{F,T\}$ under $\land$ and $\lor$ _is_ isomorphic to the integers modulo 2 under $xy$ and $x+y-xy$. (Since the integers modulo 2 form a field, this correspondence makes _linear algebra_ techniques applicable to some Boolean problems).

Comment: ... and perhaps with $x\cdot y=\min(x,y)$ and $x+y=\max(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to drhab's comment, even if we use addition mod $2$, there is no isomorphism between the two systems.  $x+x=0$ for all $x=0,1$ in modulo $2$, so $x+x$ is a constant function.   But $x\wedge x=x$ and $x\vee x=x$ for $x=\mathbf{True},\mathbf{False}$, so both $x\wedge x$ and $x\vee x$ are not constant functions.

What you can do is show that $\{\mathbf{True},\mathbf{False}\}$ along with $\wedge$ is isomorphic to $\{0,1\}$ with $\cdot$.  I take the map $f:\{\mathbf{True},\mathbf{False}\}\to\{0,1\}$ with $f(\mathbf{True})=1$ and $f(\mathbf{False})=0$.  So, $$f(x\wedge y)=f(x)\cdot f(y).$$
Similarly,  you can show that $\{\mathbf{True},\mathbf{False}\}$ along with $\vee$ is isomorphic to $\{0,1\}$ with $\cdot$.  I take the map $g:\{\mathbf{True},\mathbf{False}\}\to\{0,1\}$ with $f(\mathbf{True})=0$ and $f(\mathbf{False})=1$.  So, $$g(x\vee y)=g(x)\cdot g(y).$$